# Ruby: Will pessimist lock (self.lock!) work using update_all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, race-condition

I don't want to use `save!` method, will pessimist lock (self.lock!) work using the `update_all` method?

`lock!` using `save!` method.

```
Account.transaction do
  self.lock!
  account1 = Account.find(...)
  account1.balance -= 100
  account1.save!
end
```

`lock!` using `update_all` method.

```
Account.transaction do
  self.lock!
  attributes["balance"] = recalculate_balance
  Account.where(:id => self.id).update_all(attributes)
end
```

`Rails::VERSION::STRING => "3.2.22.4"`

Comment: Is it rails 3 or 4?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `ruby -v
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sorry my mistake.  `Rails::VERSION::STRING
=> "3.2.22.4"`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `update_all` also releases the lock.

**But:** In the code you provided you are locking row inside a transaction. It won't release this lock because transaction is locking this row anyway. It will be relesed with transaction commit.